# Android - Adaptive icon wired on Huawei devices

Tags: android, android-resources, adaptive-icon

I am using adaptive icon in my app with two .png files as background and foreground.

[image: this a normally look]

It looks good on emulator and my phone, but when I install it to a Huawei device (EMUI/Harmony), it **turns into square shape** weirdly with **both layers scale to the same size** and **no adaptive icon effect**.

.png files are *512x512 px*. (is this a problem?)

---

my adaptive icon xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/..." />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/..." />
</adaptive-icon>
```

my androidmanifest.xml:

```xml
...
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/adaptive"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/adaptive"
        ...
           >
...
```

---

The default icon and my app icon, they are **both adaptive**.

[image: adaptive icon]

but, this is only happens in the launcher, in other lists, it is round masked.

---

huawei app's icon, they are **not adaptive** and not masked.

[image: huawei's app icon]

---

How should I fix it? Anyone know? Thx

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @A.Ferrand I just changed its dimension, as generated in Android Studio, it correctly displayed now.